# psycopg2 - sum of prices

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I seem to have relatively easy question, but I have a little problem. I would like to iterr through the column prices in table products and then sum the prices.
I know an easy solution would be to change sql query -> sum(price), but in my exercise I need to avoid this solution.

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host='host',
    user='user', 
    password='password',  
    dbname='dbname', 
)

cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "select price from products"
cursor.execute(sql)

for price in cursor:
    print(sum(price))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the cursor directly:

```py
    column_sum = sum(row[0] for row in cursor)
```

Or you can use one of the various "fetch" methods to access the results and save them to a variable first.

Your cursor has 3 methods for fetching:

1. `fetchone()` returns a single row
2. `fetchmany(n)` returns a list of n many rows
3. `fetchall()` returns a list of all rows

```py
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    column_sum = sum(row[0] for row in results)
```

Note that in all cases one row of data is a tuple.  This is the case even if you're only selecting one column (a 1-tuple).

Answer (score 0):

figured it out:

```
sum = 0
for price in cursor:
    sum = sum + price[0]
print(sum)
```